# Mime Type (or something) So iOS Mail Does Not Open in Quicklook?

Tags: ios, quicklook

I've been following the brilliant instructions [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2781290/8047), which work perfectly. However, my file type is mime "application/notforquicklook" and quicklook still tries to open it. This causes general gear spinning and nothing happening.

How can I get around this problem? My files are compressed plists. Before I was using full XML plists, which worked fine, but they are too big (with no advantage).

Is this a question of choosing the right MIME type, or something else?

Comment: Hi @TheLearner... nope, did not find a solution. I'll check your answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in fact, you should assign "public.data" to your "Conforms to UTIs" (UTTypeConformsTo) in "Exported Type UTIs" (CFBundleDocumentTypes)

```
<dict>
    <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
    <array>
        <string>public.data</string>
    </array>
    <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
    <string>Scrollshow Presentation</string>
    <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.plimse.scrollshow</string>
    <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
    <dict>
        <key>public.filename-extension</key>
        <string>scrollshow</string>
        <key>public.mime-type</key>
        <string>mime/x-scrollshow</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: really psyched to try this out. also makes the other make sense.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, remove this from the xxx-info.plist file:

```
<key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
<array>
    <string>public.xml</string>
</array>
```

Now only my app shows up in the mail app.

Comment: that's not in the plist I referenced.

Comment: actually this was a good point. Sorry I didn't realize it at the time.